# Dynamically set Email Subject in Serilog

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

Could you please let me know how to configure email subject dynamically in Serilog ?

Using Output Template as : [Test] [LOCAL] - {Message}

In the above template, i want {message} as a dynamic text.

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to use a template for the email subject.

Tracking issue: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-email/issues/24

Comment: I have raised this concern.

Answer (score 1):

This has now been released, so if you update the nuget package to [`version 2.2.0`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-email/pull/26), you can now include properties in the subject line.